# Why am I getting a contradiction?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f(x,y) = xy$ and define $$C = \{ (x,y) : xy \geq 1 \}.$$

The Hessian of this function is indefinite and has positive and negative eigenvalues. But we know the set $C$ is convex since this is just the epigraph of $1/x$. So what is wrong?

**Addendum**: $$epi(f) = -C = \{(x,y): -xy \leq -1 \}$$

$$H(f) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$Det(H) = -1 <0$$ so it is concave. But $xy  \geq 1$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Have you analyzed separately the Hessian for $x>0$ and for $x<0$?

Comment: The Hessian turned out to be the identity but the columns are swapped, so no cases to consider.

Comment: Of course there are cases to consider. The graph of $C$ does not cross the $y$-axis, so it is not convex. If you "know" that $C$ is convex, then you are restricting the domain of $C$, and the same restriction applies to the Hessian.

Comment: What have you considered as the "contradiction"? You need the entire epigraph of $f$ to be convex, not just one slice of it.

Comment: What do you mean "entire"? Isn't $C$ the entire graph?

Comment: $C$ has two connected components, each of which is separately convex. However, the union is not convex.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the connected components please? I don't see it

Comment: Can you draw a picture of $C$? What does it look like?

Comment: Okay, one second.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, okay I know what you mean now. I missed the other branch, but it still doesn't explain the cases $x >0 $ and $x<0$ because the Hessian doesn't depend on that at all.

Answer (score 1):

The sublevel sets of a function are convex if the function is convex. However, the reverse is *not* true. If the sublevels sets of a function are convex, then the function is called quasiconvex, but it need not be convex.

For example, on the domain $x,y \ge 0$, the function $f(x,y)=-xy$ is quasiconvex, but not convex. There is no contradiction; it is simply an example of why quasiconvex functions are strictly more general than convex functions.

To check that $f$ is quasiconvex, we just need to check the sets $S_a=\{(x,y) \ | \ -xy \le a, \ x,y\ge 0 \}$ are convex for all $a$. For $a\ge0$, $S_a$ is the entire positive quadrant. For $a <0$, this is equivalent to $-y-a/x \le 0$, a sublevel set of a convex function.

For more about quasiconvexity, see section 3.4 of [Boyd Vandenberghe](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). It gives some general conditions you can use to check quasiconvexity.

Comment: So what was my mistake?

Comment: I guess you're assuming that the sublevel set of a nonconvex function can't be convex, which is wrong. (Incidentally, the determinant of the Hessian being negative does not imply that f is concave. In fact, f is neither convex nor concave.)

Comment: Yes, the determinant part was red-herring. I meant to explain that the Hessian has positive and negative e-values and the conclusion is as you stated. How did you check the quasi convexity thing? I've never heard of it. I know hyperbolas are supposed to be convex.

Comment: Added some more detail to address your questions.

Answer (score 0):

What @p.s writes also work in one dimension: $f(x) = \tfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ is not convex, but all the sets $\{x\ :\ f(x) < c\}$ are convex (as they are intervals). I.e. $f$ is quasiconvex but not convex.